# error when pressing enter in an input text

Tags: html, jsp

In my web page: which is a jsp file
I have an input text, I type a text in it then I press enter an error occurs:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Request[/myAction] does not contain handler parameter named 'method'.  This may be caused by whitespace in the label
text.
```

What can be the cause?

Comment: can you show how you are calling your action?

Comment: just I have:<nested:text property="adminName" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hit enter in one of the text inputs, browsers will act like the first button on the form was pressed & IE will not send any button related information to the server.

To avoid it all and make one input act just like multiple inputs, just add a 'hidden' text input

```
<input type="text" style="display: none" />
```

This input will force IE to act like the first button on the page was clicked when enter is pressed on this form.

For further info, go to [Click here](http://frustratedprogrammer.blogspot.in/2004/07/ie-bug-and-struts-forms-with-one-input.html)